# My old method of getting the access token through getAccessToken on FB does not work anymore?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0

I am trying to get the application access token to use it in my configuration file, however I can not get it even though the user accepts the app from facebook.

It used to work back in the days but not now. Before I was getting a long string of token but now, my old method does not work so I tried to get it through

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
            client_id=YOUR_APP_ID
           &client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET
           &grant_type=client_credentials
```

However what I get now is `xxxxxxxxxxxx|yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy` and I believe this is not the correct one because it does not work also.

`$facebook->getAccessToken();` used to do the trick but not now.

What can I do about it ?

Thank you

Comment: Please the downvoter tell me why did you down vote this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when user comes to your app, try `$facebook->getAccessTokenFromCode($_GET['code']);`
I was having same issue and this one fixed for me.

Comment: On the url when the redirection is completed back to my app there is a code=xxx do you mean this is the access token I need ?

Comment: yes, get that `code` from url parameter and use it for getting the access token. it should work.

Comment: I am sorry I can't get it working either...

Comment: This is what I get 'Call to protected method BaseFacebook::getAccessTokenFromCode()'

Comment: weird, the SDK I use has function `getAccessTokenFromCode()` public. check in base_facebook.php, it must be declared private then. If you want you can try making that function public once.